# Multiply in aggregation of django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In our View we get a JSON like this :

```json
{
    "cart":{
        "pizza": 2,
        "burger": 3
     }
}
```

The cart contains the Food's name, and the count of each Food.

My Food model looks like this:

```py
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('name'), max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False, editable=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("maximum price"), null=False, blank=False, editable=True)
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)], null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("created time"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

I'm trying to calculate the total price using the correct and annotations and aggregation functions, i.e. I want to multiply the count of each Food with its Price.

So far I have done this using a `for` loop:

```py
class OrderView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        srz_data = CartSerializer(data=request.data)
        if srz_data.is_valid():
            cart_order = srz_data.data['cart']
            foods = Food.objects.filter(name__in=cart_order)
            total_price = 0
            for i,n in cart_order.items():
                total_price += foods.get(name=i).price * n
```

And done some experiment using the `Sum` aggregation:

```py
class OrderView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        srz_data = CartSerializer(data=request.data)
        if srz_data.is_valid():
            order = srz_data.data['cart']
            f = Food.objects.filter(name__in=order).aggregate(Sum('max_price'))
```

But after a day I still couldn't find an answer for this, so if someone could help I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem will be how you *represent* data in the cart: as a dictionary with food (names) mapping on a number. This is one of the reasons why persisting a cart in the database might be better: it is easy to guarantee *referential* integrity.

Anyway, it can be fixed, but it is *ugly*. No, really.

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When


class OrderView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        srz_data = CartSerializer(data=request.data)
        if srz_data.is_valid():
            order = srz_data.data['cart']
            f = Food.objects.filter(name__in=order).annotate(
                Sum(
                    F('max_price')
                    * Case(
                        *[
                            When(name=n, then=Value(v))
                            for n, v in srz_data.items()
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )
```

we here thus essentially make a JOIN with the number of items, in SQL, but it is *ugly*, and not very efficient: joining will take *linear* time, which is one of the many reasons why this is likely *not* a good idea.